# How is the component view modified when keyboard is showing?

Tags: react-native

Good morning, this is actually my first question on StackOverflow after a few years in the industry (hope it's not too late!).

I'm working as a side project on a react native app.
I fail to understand how does the view change when the keyboard is up.

When the view shrinks (because the keyboard was shown), views overlap one to another. I want them to still be split.

I have this picture showing what I mean with overlapping views:

[image: Image showing what I meant with overlapping views]

I thought it might be something with the paddings/margins, but I removed them all and still the same issue. Now, I know that the input height is defined by an absolute number, and that is what makes it not shrink, so it is bigger than the actual view, that's why it overlaps.

How can I keep my input having a fixed height but also maintaining a margin of separation when the view shrinks ??

Thank you very much!

Edit: I'm editing because I feel like I haven't been able to express my idea of how I need it to work. (Should I delete previous explanation? Keep picture if someone edits and deletes the first explanation).

The initial view with no keyboard has to be like this:

[image: Initial screen]

The inputs and buttons have to be at the bottom, the view getting all the height possible.

When opening the keyboard (by clicking on one of the inputs), I want the list to shrink so that the buttons and inputs are still visible and separated by a small margin/padding, and the list to have taken the remaining space (again respecting a small separation between views). The list will still be scrollable (it is a FlatList) when opening the keyboard.

Thank you again and sorry for the misexplanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping your content inside a ScrollView instead of a normal View like this:

```js
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>/* your content here */</ScrollView>
```

So when the keyboard shows up your elements won't overlap since they take the same space but you can scroll to see the elements hidden by the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this:

```
<View>
    <ScrollView>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex:1}} behavior={Platform.select({ios:"padding", android:null })} keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.select({ios: 0, android: 500})}>
            {/*Your buttons and other elements here...*/}
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </ScrollView>
<View>
```

You will also have to import `KeyboardAvoidingView` and `ScrollView` from `react-native` for this.